# HTML iFrame hide/show

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, file-upload, upload

I have a upload option on my website with an iframe. So here's my html:

```
<iframe name="message" src="upload.php"></iframe>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="message">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The problem now is the iframe is visible when they go to the upload portion of the site. I want it to be invisible UNTIL it receives a response from upload.php, upon which I want it to show the message like an alert box which you can read then close. How do I go about doing that? I'm guessing there is some jquery involved.

Comment: Umm, give it the hidden attribute, then remove it when the script responds? What are you asking? The methodology is quite simple.

Comment: @thatidiotguy obviously i don't know the methodology if I'm asking the question T.T if you can't already tell, i'm pretty damn new to web development.

Comment: Michael, that is fine, but if you want answers, you are going to have to formulate better questions. You did not specify whether your PHP file is running synchronously or not, whether that PHP file is outputting this iframe, what is calling the PHP file, what Javascript you alread have etc. I am a coder, not a seer.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the iframe (or other HTML element) just add: `style="display:none;"` in that HTML tag.

Then you can add in the PHP response a javascript code to call a function from parent page. Something like this:

```
// ..
echo '<script>
parent.functionName();
</script>';
```

In that function add the JavaScript instructions you want to be executed after the php response.

Comment: Well i want to use something like fancybox so i can hide the iframe. So I would have something like `Function( iframe.fancybox());` and then in upload.php i would do `parent.Function();` is that right?