# PHP Showing iFrame on Response

Tags: php, html, iframe, file-upload, fancybox

I had an earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712814/html-iframe-hide-show) but the answer didn't help at all. I have an upload feature like this:

```
<iframe class="iframe" name="message" src="upload.php" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="message">
    Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And i'm trying to do something like this:

```
$('.iframe').fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
});
```

So when upload.php gives a response ("file successfully uploaded") it goes into the iframe which is great. But I need the iframe to show. How do I unhide the iframe after upload.php has responded with a message?

Comment: Are you doing this request with AJAX?

Comment: Are you submitting your form through AJAX?

Comment: You should look into something known as AJAX. It allows your user to stay on the same page and make requests to the server. JQuery makes that really simple, because you won't have to worry about the boilerplate that is cross browser compatibility.

Comment: @JustinWood is there any way to do what I want with what I have or do I **HAVE** to use ajax?

Comment: @MichaelBenneton You don't **HAVE** to use any technology. AJAX will just prevent the user from navigating to another page. If you don't use AJAX, the user will be navigated away from the current page you're on, and you will have to display whatever it is you're trying to display on that second page, or any other number of pages after (depending on if you want to forward the user to yet another page).

Comment: You should apply fancybox to the selector that FIRES fancybox, not to the selector, which is the (targeted) content you try to open in fancybox. Is this fancybox v1.3.4??

Comment: @JustinWood well the page doesn't redirect instead it just outputs all the messages to the iframe, so since i'm not redirecting does that mean i'm using ajax?

Comment: Most likely.. Do you have something like `$.ajax`, `$.post` or `$.get` in your javascript somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to have an inline iframe? You could try to `submit` the form via ajax and display the response in fancybox without the inline iframe like

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="message">
    Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Notice** that I added an **ID** to the form so we can manipulate it through that selector. Then the jQuery  :

```
$("#uploadForm").bind("submit", function() {
 $.ajax({
   type     : "POST",
   cache    : false,
   url      : "upload.php",
   success  : function(data) {
    $.fancybox(data.responseText,{
      'hideOnContentClick': true
    });
   }
 });
 return false;
});
```

Comment: This didn't work, the iframe didn't display anything after uploading a file.

Comment: this solution doesn't use an iframe